# adding a link to to a table in mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink

Can someone please show me where i am going wrong with this, i am echoing out some mysql results in a query using a table format, and i am trying to make the row of results clickable so a user can click on it an link to another page.

i dont understand why its not working

```
<?php include 'config.php';
         $data = mysql_query("SELECT *, TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, insurance_date, CURDATE()) AS expire_date FROM supplier_stats ORDER BY expire_date DESC") 
         or die(mysql_error()); 

         echo "<table class=\"table\" style=\"width:995px;  font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
         font-size:11px;\" >

    <tr>
        <td style=\"width:100px;\">ID:</td><td>Company Name:</td><td>Company Reg No:</td><td>Owner:</td><td style=\"width:200px;\">Note:</td><td style=\"width:100px;\">Date:</td><td>Status:</td></tr>";


         while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) { 
            $days = $row['expire_date'];
            $when = $days*-1; 
            $str = $row['expire_date'];
            $str2 = substr($str, 1); // "quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."
           if ($when <= 31){
           echo "<a href=\"test.php\"><tr><td style=\"width:100px;\"><p>".$row['id'] . "</p></td>"; 
           echo "<td style=\"width:150px;\"><p>".$row['company_name'] . "</p></td>"; 
           echo "<td style=\"width:150px;\"><p>".$row['company_reg_number'] . "</p></td>";
           echo "<td style=\"width:100px;\"><p>".$row['owner'] . "</p></td>";


           if ($days > 0) {
                echo "<td style=\"width:200px;\"><p><font color=\"red\">Insurance expired!</font>";  
                echo "<td>";
                echo date('d/m/Y',strtotime($row['insurance_date']));
      echo"</td>";
                if ($when >= 7){ echo "<font color=\"green\">{$row['expire_date']}</font> day(s)!</p></td>";  }
            } else {
              $when = $days*-1;           

              echo "<td style=\"width:200px;\"><p>Insurance expires";

              if ($when > 1){
                  if ($when >= 20){ 
                  echo " in <font color=\"green\">{$str2}</font> days</font></td>"; }
                  elseif ($when >= 8){ 
                  echo " in <font color=\"orange\">{$str2}</font> days</font></td>"; }
                  elseif ($when <= 7){ 
                  echo " in <font color=\"red\">{$str2}</font> days</font></td>"; }

              } elseif ($when >= 1){ 
                echo "<font color=\"red\"> tomorrow!</font></td>";
              }
            elseif ($when >= 0){ 

                echo "<font color=\"red\"> today!</font></p></td>";
            }

            echo "<td>";
              echo date('d/m/Y',strtotime($row['insurance_date']));


      echo"</td>";


            }

            if ($when >= 20){
                echo "<td style=\"width:150px;\"><div class=\"green_light\"></div></td>";

            }

            elseif ($when >= 8){
                echo "<td style=\"width:150px;\"><div class=\"amber_light\"></div></td>";
              }

              if ($when <= 7){
                echo "<td style=\"width:150px;\"><div class=\"red_light\"></div></td>";
              }


            echo "<tr></a>";
          }
         }

          echo "</table>"; //Close the table in HTML


        ?>
```

Comment: your tr tags are wrong, put `a` tag in side tr not outside

Comment: You can't put an `<a>` tag as a child of `<table>`.

Comment: The `<a>` tag has to be inside `<td>`. The hierarchy has to be `<table> -> <tr> -> <td> -> stuff`.

Comment: ive done this but still not linking

Comment: If you want to make the whole row clickable, put an `onclick` attribute in the `<tr>`

Comment: the link is not working, so that means its not linking

Comment: why its not working ... http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ code review

Comment: @J.Tural At Code Review SE, asking for help with broken code is off-topic.

Comment: off topic here ... this Q should be edited or closed no one will get benefit from it like this

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways to do this:

**Using javascript:**

```
<tr onclick="document.location = 'links.html';">
```

**Using anchors:**

```
<tr><td><a href="">text</a></td><td><a href="">text</a></td></tr>
```

**I made the second work using:**

```
table tr td a {
    display:block;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

To get rid of the dead space between columns:

```
table tr td {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

***This will work really work***

I should say thanks [Voyager](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34813/voyager)

Comment: the problem with this though is that i am going to want each row to link to a seperate url so row one might be test.php?id=1 and the next row might be test.php?id=3 so the link needs to be part of the mysql query it can not be a standard html link

Comment: I will give you an answer now, but You said want to have a table link not a row link

Answer (score 0):

it is not allowed to use the `p` tag within an `a` tag

add this css-code to your css file

```
a {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot open

```
<a> before <tr>

because <table> <tr> <td> must be sequential
```

you can use other syntax like :

```
<td colspan="8"> <a> bla bla bla </a> </td>
```